# MediaWiki security: Alternate file ayout

Tags: php, linux, mediawiki

The default file layout of MediaWiki seems quite insecure and good apps expose a single directory (and not the entire hierarchy) to http requests. I've tried to follow instructions found on: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Security#Alternate_file_layout

And created a /web directory under the base installation directory /wiki and in it created two new files /wiki/web/index.php that looks like

```
<?php
chdir('../');
require_once 'index.php';
```

A similar /weiki/web/load.php was created. I've also added a soft link to the resources directory so /wiki/web/resource is actually /wiki/resources

The first request on the wiki (after restarting the server and setting the document root to /wiki/web instead of /wiki) does respond and shows the page well. However, subsequent responses produce a blank page with code 200 (success). Nothing comes up in the PHP error log either. As this happens after subsequent restarts I suspect some caching mechanism isn't working properly.

Any ideas on how to find the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That `chdir('../');` doesn't sound right. You should use an absolute path as demonstrated in the manual you linked, apparently in your case `chdir('/wiki/web/');`

However, before going through such adventures, I hope you protected the actually sensitive paths like configuration files, uploads and cache... (See the manuals for the setup of those.)

Comment: I've formerly tried with both absolute and relative paths. As I wrote in the question, the first request is answered properly. The rest of your suggestion is not clear. If only specific directories are exposed publicly, obviously all others would be protected.